# Dynamic layout with imageViews

Tags: android, android-layout

Please help me create layout like this screen:
[image]

Images position need to be like on the screen. All time images scaling or resize borders.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <view
            class=".widget.AvatarView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/view6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <view
                class=".widget.AvatarView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <view
                class=".widget.AvatarView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/view11"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <view
            class=".widget.AvatarView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/view5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <view
            class=".widget.AvatarView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/view8"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

        </view>

        <view
            class=".widget.AvatarView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/view10"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

        </view>

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

But images need not scaling and resizing!
I'm receive [image] Please help, thanks!

Comment: Try [`GridLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) maybe?

Comment: Instead of `TableLayout` use `LinearLayout` with padding, orientation and weight property.

Comment: @HimanshuAgarwal I can't do stretchy with linear layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this sample layout and you can customize this for your own

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I need behaviour like tinder app on the screenshot on top.

Comment: yes from this code you can edit according to your need it give output similar to above layout image

Comment: I my logic, some count images can be empty, others images is stretchy, i don't want it! How make it?

Comment: try using weight property and set height and width to wrap_content

Comment: I doing like you say please see attached layout code in question post. But it's doesen't help!